# How to install FFMPEG in Openshift?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, openshift, redhat

I saw this tutorial but couldn't make it work

https://medium.com/ken-m-lai/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-openshift-d975a6a91d9e#.wvsok37v1

It fails in this steps:

> cd ffmpeg-2.0.1
>
> make
>
> make install

The `make` command and the `make install` says some files couldn't be found:

```
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:48: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:91: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:91: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:168: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:169: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Both throws the same erros.
Anyone knows how to install FFMPEG on Openshift or how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Type './configure' to create the configuration. A list of configure
>   options is printed by running 'configure --help'.
>
> 'configure' can be launched from a directory different from the FFmpeg
>   sources to build the objects out of tree. To do this, use an absolute
>   path when launching 'configure', e.g. '/ffmpegdir/ffmpeg/configure'.
>
> 2) Then type 'make' to build FFmpeg. GNU Make 3.81 or later is
>   required.
>
> 3) Type 'make install' to install all binaries and libraries you
>   built.
>
> NOTICE
>
> - Non system dependencies (e.g. libx264, libvpx) are disabled by default.

If you read the INSTALL readme, it says to run `./configure` first, have you done that?

I don't have any way to test this, but looking at the source of the file, it seems to create the config.mak at some point